# Inconsistency between pop and peek in a Stack: looking for an explanation

Tags: xtend

I have a program which uses a stack of sets of elements. The context here does not really matter. The code contains the following instructions:

```
val last = current_stack.pop
current_stack.peek.addAll(last)
```

At some point, I factored them as followed:

```
current_stack.peek.addAll(current_stack.pop)
```

To my surprise, the program behaved differently.

**Does anybody have an explanation for this difference in behaviour?**

Comment: Well yeah, in the first code snippet `pop` is executed before `peek`, but in the second code snippet, `peek` is executed before `pop`.

Comment: but why ? I have always assumed that when calling a function the parameters would be evaluated first.

Comment: Yeah, but in the second code snippet, you are calling `addAll` on the result of `peek`, so before you can even call `addAll`, `peek` has to be called first.

Comment: What is 'peek'?  This knowledge is crucial to understanding what the code does.  How does it relate to the 'peek()' method of the Java Stack class?  Is 'peek' a call on 'peek()'?

Comment: @dilettante `.peek` is just a shorthand for `.peek()`

Comment: @Sweeper Yes I agree that `peek` has to be called before `addAll`, but still the argument could be evaluated before all of these are.

Comment: @MrO Well it certainly *could*, but that's not how the language is designed. We are now at the point where [you need to clarify what kind of answer you are looking for.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio)

Comment: @Sweeper so you are saying that specifically in xtend, the object on which a method is called is evaluated before the arguments of the method? That's interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like xtend just compiles down to Java, so assuming that this translation is relatively straightforward (and doens't reorder parts of the expression), let's take a look at the equivalent Java:

```
var last = current_stack.pop()
current_stack.peek().addAll(last)

// vs

current_stack.peek().addAll(current_stack.pop())
```

The java spec generally says that things are operated [left to right](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7), outside of things like parenthesis and operator precedence. For method invocation specifically, [section 15.12.4 (JLS 21)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4) says:

> At run time, method invocation requires five steps. First, a target reference may be computed. Second, the argument expressions are evaluated. …

Here, the target reference is the object that comes from `current_stack.peek()`. Per the Java spec, this gets evaluated before the argument expressions — and in particular, in your second example, it gets evaluated before `current_stack.pop()`.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I was looking for.